# Terse introduction to complex analysis of a single variable

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I'm very interested in learning about complex manifolds. I've had an undergraduate course in complex analysis, and I'll take a grad course in the subject eventually, but for now is there a short/terse introduction to complex analysis that will give me the working knowledge to start learning about complex manifolds?

Comment: Do you mean complex analysis in one variable or several?

Comment: Ah, one variable. I'll edit it to make this clear.